# Quoting a Python function in order to apply it later

Tags: python

Given an object Foo, which has a set of methods Bar, Baz, Quux, and Close.

I want to wrap calls into Foo as follows

```
def wrapper(method_symbol, *args):
   object = Foo()
   apply(object.method_symbol, args)
   object.Close()
```

So later on, I can call `wrapper(Bar, MySweetArgs)` and have wrapper correctly dispatch.

Obviously in Lisp this would be simple, simply `QUOTE method_symbol` and away you go.

The goal is to properly allocate/deallocate resources in a text-efficient fashion. I would prefer not wrap all of Foo with a SafeFoo class.

Comment: What is a "text-efficient fashion"?

Comment: @mike: I don't want to have to write a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: @agf: It's just a method on Foo.

Comment: I assume you meant to use `obj.method_symbol` instead of `Foo.method_symbol`?

Comment: @interjay: Whoops. Yes. Editing now.

Comment: "The goal is to properly allocate/deallocate resources" sounds like you want the `with` statement.

Comment: Jochen is right; if you `from contextlib import closing` then just do `with closing(Foo()) as object:` instead of `object = Foo()`, and properly use the lower case method name for `close()`, it will close the object even if there is an exception raised during the `apply` step.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to call the method by its name, the `wrapper` function could look like this:

```
def wrapper(method_symbol, *args):
   obj = Foo()
   getattr(obj, method_symbol)(*args)
   obj.Close()

wrapper('Bar', 1, 2, 3)
```

You could also use the method directly, instead of its name:

```
def wrapper(method, *args):
   obj = Foo()
   method(obj, *args)
   obj.Close()

wrapper(Foo.Bar, 1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score -1):

If method_symbol is the string name then:

```
Foo.__dict__[method_symbol](*args)
```

would probably do it.

Comment: Not if it's an instance method.

Comment: True, you'd have to push obj onto the beginning of args to act as self.  sth's answer is better.